# How to return the object in Min predicate in c#?

Tags: c#

In c#, I have this code

```
Pixel topLeft = potentialTopLeft.Min(p => p.GetX());
```

Which gets the smallest Pixel object in the list `potentialTopLeft`, but what it uses to compare the Pixel value is the value of the `GetX()` class method. But the problem is, it returns the value of the smallest `GetX()`, and I want the Pixel object with the smallest `GetX()`. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Your `potentialTopLeft` is a collection of what? And what property in it holds the Pixel?

Comment: they are  `Pixel` object in the list

Comment: Ok..then you should get the Pixel object with min GetX value. So what else are you looking for?

Comment: It's not returning a pixel object Like I said, its returning the getX() value which is an int.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Applying **Sort** and than taking the **first element** from the `IOrderedList`:

```
var topLeft = potentialTopLeft.OrderBy(p => p.GetX()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: There isnt a method for OrderByAscending, but there is one for Descending.

Comment: @omega, Yeah written it on the fly :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to order the whole list to find the `Pixel` with minimun `X`, that will increase your code complexity. You can simply use this:

```
var minX = potentialTopLeft.Min(p => p.GetX());
Pixel topLeft = potentialTopLeft.First(p => p.GetX() == minX);
```

Comment: What if 2 Pixel objects have the same min X value? Y value might be different and `First` doesn't necessarily return the same object as the one queried in the `Min` statement.

Comment: @Saragis then he can use `.Where(p => p.GetX() == minX)` to get all objects with min X, and select the desired object from that list based on whatever he wants. Still, he doesn't need to sort the whole list.

Comment: @Saragis That actually doesn't matter though, as there is no fallback criteria to handle the case of duplicates. The other answer also just picks one with the lowest `GetX`, but in no particular order.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could have `Pixel` implement `IComparable<Pixel>` and provide a quick `CompareTo` method implementation like so:

```
class Pixel : IComparable<Pixel>
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    int IComparable<Pixel>.CompareTo(Pixel other)
    {
        if (other.X > this.X) { return -1; }
        else if (other.X == this.X) { return 0; }
        else {return 1; }
    }
}
```

With that in place you can now use the `Min` method:

```
Pixel topLeft = potentialTopLeft.Min();
```

The benefit of this approach is that it makes your calling code more readable and you can use it if you have other places in your code where you need to compare `Pixel` instances.